# Appstore: Do I have to make a new version after updating certificates?

Tags: ios, certificate, version

First thing: I am not experienced with Apple stuff, I was just thrown into this.

The certificate for an App from the Appstore was running out. I renewed the certificate and the provisioning profile, downloaded them, added them to the Keychain. Then I compiled the App again, using the new certificates.

I now have to upload this newly compiled app to the appstore, am I right ?
Also I can not just replace the current binary for the current version, I need to make a new Version in order to upload the new binary, is that correct ? Or is there a way to keep the current version number and just replace the binary (basically nothing has changed within the app itself, I feel like making a new version is unnecessary...).

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Comment: Yes, if you're updating certificates then old will be expired so you need to recreate if for development/distribution only. Haven't tried this before, but shouldn't for AppStore apps. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to increase your version number for uploading new build. If you want to keep same version number, you will have to increase your build number. Good luck.